# Why the internal server error occures while using finfo_file function?

Tags: php, file, webserver, mime-types, mime

My code is that

```
   $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
   $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $file_tmp);

   if ($mime == 'application/msword' || $mime == 'image/gif' || $mime =='image/jpeg' || $mime =="image/png") {
       move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file);
   }

   finfo_close($finfo);
}
```

**After сhecking, the problem was here `$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);`. At this point file with errors shows nothing, just a blank file, and no matter what, the problem is more likely with that function `finfo_`.**

Console writes the following after code executing:

> POST http://localhost:82/diplomna/process.php net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)

Where the mistake can be?

Comment: What debugging have you actually done? Turn on error reporting and tell us what the error is.

Comment: @Jaquarh it works, even the error.php file shows me all needed errors till the code with finfo_   function appears. And, after that, I see nothing in error.php file. Before my code was a little different, and the problem was the same,  when it comes to finfo function it doesn't work more.